How can I improve the power supply for my Arduino-based sensor system?
I am working on an Arduino-based sensor system that includes a temperature sensor, a humidity sensor, and an LCD display. Everything works fine, but I am facing issues with power stability when I run the system for extended periods.
The sensors sometimes stop responding, and the LCD display flickers occasionally. I am currently powering the system using a 9V battery, but I suspect that the power supply might not be sufficient or stable enough for continuous operation.
I was considering switching to a regulated power supply, but I’m not sure which type would be best suited for this setup. Should I go with a linear regulator or a switching regulator? Are there any specific products that are recommended for Arduino-based systems?
Additionally, I found this DC-DC Convertor which seems like a good option. Has anyone used something similar in their projects? Any feedback or alternative recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

May you link the board you are using?

9V batteries may seem convenient but are generally not recommended for systems that run for a long time. An exception might obviously be smoke alarms, but they are specifically designed to have low current draws.
If you are using something like a Uno, and plugging in a 9V battery, then the voltage regulator immediately converts that to 5V, throwing away the rest as heat.
You are much better off using, say, 3 AA batteries in a battery holder (giving a nominal total of 4.5V) and connecting that directly to the 5V pin of your Arduino.
Then I would set it up to sleep, consuming much less power when it is not actually taking readings.
I did a temperature and humidity sensor, described here which runs for a couple of years before needing battery replacement.
I also have some tips for low power usage.
Related post on this site: Arduino minimal power usage

Assuming you want your system to work as long as possible with the battery, you should consider changing your elements:

Do NOT use Arduino Uno or similar, but go for a Pro Mini (3V3/8MHz) with no LED.
Select a low consumption display. e-ink are best, as they do not consume anything as long as you don't change the display.
Look at "sleeping" capabilities of your system. There are a few libraries or articles explaining how you can put your system to sleep and only wake up every x minutes.
Consider using a 1.5V battery and a boost DC-DC converted.

One AA battery will last weeks if you are following the above recommendations. I have one such system running since 10 years at home, and I change my battery roughly every year.

You can always tie multiple batteries in parallel for more current, use a bigger 9v battery, or go with any 9v power supply. If your sensors are analog, you may need to use a linear power supply because they make less noise. If the sensors are digital, switching should work fine. I think all of the sensors would be 5v, if so, a 5v power supply would work as long as it has enough current to run all the sensors, and Arduino. DC-DC converters aren't really want you are looking for unless your power supplies are too high of a voltage or if you need two separate voltages. With Arduino, I usually connect a 12V power supply to VIN so that I have 12V, and 5v 3.3v from the Arduino. When you connect your sensors, try not to draw too much from the Arduino. The pins can only supply so much.
